# JavaScript functionalities not applied when linking an external .js file in flask app

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm working on a flask application. I've made a .htm file and I need to write some javascript code for the web page. I first wrote the code in an external file but while running my flask app, the javascript functionalities were not applied. But when I included all the js code in the .htm file itself (within the script tag), then they were being applied.
These are the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript CDNs that I have linked. I'm thinking these are overriding the code written in the external .js file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

This is how I'm linking my external .js file.

```
<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='index.js')}}"></script>
```

How can I link my external .js file so that those functionalities will get applied?
This is my folder structure:

[image: This is my folder structure]

This is how I have included the Bootstrap js CDNs and my .js file:

[image: This is how I have included the Bootstrap js CDNs and my .js file]

Comment: Look in your browser's network inspector. Are you getting 404 errors for any assets?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the JavaScript might not load due to the encoding.
Set the encoding to `UTF-8` and it will work.
Here is the code:

```html
<head>
  <!-- set encoding to utf-8 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Adding your CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Adding your viewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
   <!-- all other code of your file -->

   <!-- Add JavaScript in the end of the contents in body -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

EDIT:
According to the picture you have given, use this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/index.js"></script>
```

You have to write it as `../static/index.js` in your `script src`

Comment: Added UTF-8 encoding but still didn't work. I have added a screenshot of my code. Could you please check it?

Comment: I have edited the answer to add the index.js in your html file.